# Mission and Safety Critical RF System

Tags: rf, esp8266

EE.SE

I'm working on a amature high power rocketry project, in which a 4 inch rocket with multiple tracking systems and igniters are used to deploy chutes and ignite a  second stage. Traditionally, we run wires from screw terminals down to igniters. This works, but is difficult to integrate, and wires can break under the shock and vibe. ([This](http://www.asahi.com/ajw/articles/AJ201802040016.html) Japanese rocket project broke last year likely due to a wire failure)

We are currently using ESP8266 modules connected to temperature and strain gauge sensors to collect structural data about the rocket. This works, but these sensors are not mission critical.

We would like to move to a wireless system linking the several avionics bays, altimeters, sensors, charges, etc. However, this thing is a safety hazard if it fails, and so we need to evaluate the reliability of this.

Does anything have experience with high reliability short range RF systems? Is the ESP8266 a valid choice, or should we be using something like 433Mhz? (our current air<->ground RF link).

Thanks for the feedback. Also feel free to brainstorm, as anything we decide on will go through lots of review before it ever sees the light of day.

Thanks

Tim

Edit: Clarification
This is not a question of long range communication between the rocket and the ground, that is already handled. This is a matter of communication between the altimeter electronics and various other components in the same airframe. I dont think bit error rate is really the  issue in this case (correct me if I'm wrong). The proposed ESP8266 system has a strong link and has never failed for the sensors. the issues is how to qualify a system to not fail for a more important role.

Comment: Might want to edit "armature" into "amateur??" This is a multistage rocket and you are talking about communications between stages here? Or are you talking about ground control (which I doubt since you are talking about going from a wired system to a wireless one, if I'm reading correctly?) Or both?

Comment: Can you define the acceptible probability of error , translate that to BER then CNR then Tx power level and Rx threshold , antenna gains apply Friis Loss and add antenna null margin or add redundancy

Comment: Please justify why wires failed. Any missile I've looked at uses wires.

Comment: You can't validate the ESP's software stack, as portions of it are not accessible to you. You can only validate the hardware for the extreme environment. For such applications, I would contact the manufacturer and have an FAE look at my design.

Comment: You may want to look into NRF24L01-based modules for medium range RF comms. Some rather small modules seem to go by the name "RFM70" or "RFM73". Features: Fully digital, packet-based RF comms @ 2.4GHz, up to 2Mbps, configurable TX power, 125 RF channels to choose from, communication from one transceiver to up to six others ("MultiCeiver").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wires! Seriously.

Wireless for pyro control is done, but it is far from trivial and is almost always less reliable then wiring done correctly.

NASA have some very good reliability briefing documents on how to terminate wiring, how to solder and how to inspect the work for spacecraft applications, well worth tracking down.

It is not so much the radio bit itself as the fact that your radios built in software is now safety and mission critical, and most modules really are not qualified for that kind of use. Consider also that such things as staging never want to be triggerable by a single circuit component failing, you don't want some mosfet suffering a SEU to cause the thing to stage while being fitted to the rail. Everything of that nature should have separate (and monitored!) arm and fire circuitry, interlocked appropriately, and include appropriate error states in the state machines.

Finely stranded flexible wire is your friend together with ample strain relief and joints which are mechanically secure before you solder them (Or, better, crimp them with the right tools, crimp done right is better then solder in high vibration environments).

Also, include monitoring and testing circuitry, if your igniter needs an amp to light off, can you (after the pad is clear) run 1mA thru everything automatically to measure resistance and verify no shorts or opens?

Finally, redundancy does not hurt, you are probably not pushing the limits of the rocket equation and chemical propellant ISP, so two sets of electronics and doubled up igniters, staging and recovery deployment systems are just going to make for a slightly larger motor and not be the mass disaster they would be if at the limits of ISP and mass fraction.

One surprisingly useful radio thing is a simple beacon built with a low phase noise VHF source and AM modulated with simple tone based telemetry. The doppler on the carrier gives you relative velocity and the low frequency am component gives you roll rate if you use a dipole setup such that the rotation of the rocket changes the losses, meanwhile the level of the tones transmits useful things like pressures, temperatures and maybe even strain gauge readings.

A  modern SDR with CP or crossed polarisation aerials can easily give almost real time data from such a thing, and if you have a 4 channel sync sampling setup you can even get bearing without needing to rely on GPS. The nice thing about this is that it degrades more gracefully then a digital transmitter will, your uncertainty values increase as the signal gets weaker, but you can still get something a long way down into the noise where a digital telemetry link will have just stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

One of my 1st antenna designs was in the VHF band fora Black Brandt 6.  I used a radial spun dipole and the design worked to several hundred miles up and down but on the way down it was farther away and near atmosphere dead spots would cause LOS ( loss of signal twice per rotation. )

All antenna have deadspots in the 3D radiation pattern, so SNR can span a wide range. I had super sensitive quad helix ground station tracking antenna. You may not have this luxury.

For wire breakage, my experience taught me to tack all wires with polyurethane to prevent vibration, especially at ends with a certain strain relief thickness ratio like good headphone plugs.  On HDD voice coils with flex circuits if the wires move axially instead of radially, they can survive 100Million seeks.